# HotModuleReplacement not connecting

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack

I am currently trying to use webpack for the first time in a project and have set up a ASP.NET Core project with the following in the Startup.cs file

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
```

I have Styles folder which contains some .less files too and I have a webpack.config.js in the root of the project, containing:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
  return [{
    mode: 'development', //TODO Make configurable
    entry: { 'main': './app.js' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot"),
        filename: "js/[name].js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].css'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(less)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "Styles")
                ],
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'less-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
  }];
}
```

When I run my application, I can see in the output that it is compiling the webpack bundles and I see my files in the js and css folder of wwwroot, which suggests it is finding the webpack config file, I also see lines like below which suggests it is attempting something with the webpack-hot-middleware plugin:

> [./node_modules/html-entities/index.js] 231 bytes {main} [built]
>
> [./node_modules/querystring-es3/decode.js] 2.45 KiB {main} [built]
>
> [./node_modules/querystring-es3/encode.js] 2.48 KiB {main} [built]
>
> [./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js] 127 bytes {main} [built]
>
> [./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client-overlay.js 2.17 KiB {main} [built]
>
> [./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true] (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true 7.68 KiB {main} [built]

but then I don't see any other reference to HMR, and I don't get the [HMR] connected line in the console to signify it has linked up.

Is there anything I am missing in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.....I was being stupid and had forgotten to actually include the is file that is output by webpack, because all I was using for at that point was to compile my less files into CSS!